# Can't access JSON values

Tags: javascript, json

I have json like this:

```
"{'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}"
```

After `JSON.parse()` my result looks like this:

```
a = {'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}
```

If I access `a.total` I get undefined. If I copy this whole thing in the browser console it's working but not on my app. What is wrong?

Code:

```
data = "{'total': '1', 'product_name': 'Cup'}"; 
parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
prod_name = parsedData.product_name;
```

Comment: You have to show the code that is calling `JSON.parse`, try to create [a simple reduction like this](http://jsfiddle.net/RWt5U/). By the way, your JSON is invalid, it should use double quotes, instead of single.

Comment: What does `console.dir(parsedData)` show you?

Comment: `There are no child objects`

Comment: @user2032220 You didn't define `data`. Be more careful, don't post code that has undefined variables.

Comment: @user2032220: Ok, how about `console.log(parsedData)`?

Comment: Looks like a timing issue to me. Are you sure you're reading a.total AFTER the json has loaded?

Comment: `console.log(parsedData)` --> `{'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}`
--> `console.log(typeof(parsedData))` --> `string`

Comment: @user2032220 — Your `parsedData` isn't parsed

Comment: @user2032220 Stop posting random code and post something that we can run!

Comment: Seems like you JSON isn't parsed.  Or it was double-encoded?  How are you making your JSON?  What does it *really* look like?  What's the *exact* JSON and how are you getting it?

Comment: Are you making an AJAX call? Are you trying to decode the JSON string outside of the AJAX callback?

Comment: It's inside the ajax call. I am using `json` module of python to convert `dict` to `json`.

Comment: @user2032220: So, are you literally adding the `"`s when you print it?  Why are the keys in single quotes, not double quotes?  Can you show the *exact* response from the AJAX call?

Comment: I am not literally adding it, that's output I got after I did `console.log(data);`

Comment: @user2032220: Something's not right here.  What is the python code to generate the JSON?  Is `"{'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}"` what you see in the "Network" tab as the AJAX call's response?

Answer (score 1):

`"{'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}"` is valid JSON - it's a single string with the value `{'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}` (i.e. it looks like an object but isn't one!).

Instead, you need to pass a string with the value `{"total": 1, "product_name": "Cup"}` to `JSON.parse` (i.e. no quotes outside the braces and double quotes for strings).

If you do this in JavaScript, it would look like so:

```
data = "{\"total\": 1, \"product_name\": \"Cup\"}";
parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

As you can see, you need to escape the quotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. JSON strings must be quoted with `"` not `'`.

- Do [test](http://jsonlint.com/) your JSON
- Avoid writing JSON by hand
- Avoid using JSON when you can use JavaScript

Such:

```
parsedData = {'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}
```

---

> ```
> console.log(parsedData)
> {'total': 1, 'product_name': 'Cup'}
> console.log(typeof(parsedData))
> string
> ```

If that is the case, then your JSON is valid, but it is just a JSON text containing a single string.

Get rid of the `"` around the JSON as well as changing the `'` inside it to `"`.

Comment: @JuanMendes It's indeed the problem.  Tested with nodejs on ubuntu.

Comment: @gongzhitaao I mean that I think the OP wrote the JSON by hand on the question. If you see my comments on the question, you'll clearly see I understand the JSON is not well formatted.